# "-" character is converted to ? in console for gherkin language used in cucumber feature file

Tags: testing, automation, cucumber, gradle, gherkin

I am using cucumber feature file to execute or write my test cases. Issue is that I am using data table as :

```
| abc  | 1234567890                                 | 
| defg | New Activation – Monthly (Credit in store) |
```

Now issue is this that console is throwing an error that :

```
Cannot locate element with text: New Activation ? Monthly (Credit in store).
```

I am not able to understand why ? is being displayed instead of "–" .

Comment: My guess would be that it is some kind of character encoding problem.

Comment: yes, but is there anyworkaround for this. i mean i am unable to automate this becouse of this issue.

Comment: Make sure the correct encoding is used (e.g. with `gradle -Dfile.encoding=... test`).